# Spring boot app with spring boot starter can't log in

Tags: spring-boot

I  make SpringBoot app, try login and get login error.

I login with name = `Bob` and password = `$2a$10$iCx6g2KD8Y/Ud8MT6TuAF.lJZOzbRiIdcBqYI5gxXg3jzP2rnHoVq`

The login check is as follows:

```
 http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin*", "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().successHandler(successUserHandler)
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

Could you help why I cannot login?
My github:
https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.4-check.git

Comment: why do you try to login with encoded password? as I understand this is the password saved in your DB or elsewhere, but you can't login with it, you should use the original raw password, to let BCryptPasswordEncoder match it with the encoded (stored) one.

Comment: When I insert login  `Bob ` and password `bob`  (as was set in database) I get message `Bad credentials`

Comment: sorry, I'm not following: your DB contains a password _"bob"_? if yes, then you won't be able to login with any credentials while you're using `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, because it expects an encoded password to be returned from `UserDetails`

Comment: Let me say again: the word “bob” was encrypted and DB contains actually the password $2a$10$iCx6g2KD8Y/Ud8MT6TuAF.lJZOzbRiIdcBqYI5gxXg3jzP2rnHoVq

Comment: I checked the web-site bcrypt-generator.com,  the word `bob` mathes with my password (hash) $2a$10$iCx6g2KD8Y/Ud8MT6TuAF.lJZOzbRiIdcBqYI5gxXg3jzP2rnHoVq  though I can not login

Answer (score 0):

I added two annotations from Lombok to @manytomany and it became working.